# how to solve the problem(@id needs to be declared) in sqladapter.InsertCommand c# ado.net

Tags: c#, sql-server, ado.net

I keep getting this error

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: La variable scalaire "@id" doit être déclarée.

on the adapter's insert command, even if my value is declared in the parameters

What should I do?

Here is the code

```
private void BT_Add_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    adapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", txtID.Text);
    adapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", txtName.Text);
    adapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lastname", txtLastName.Text);
    adapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@adress", txtAdress.Text);
    adapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", txtEmail.Text);
    connection.Open();
    adapter.InsertCommand = new SqlCommand("insert into client values(@id,@name,@lastname,@adress,@email)", connection);
    adapter.InsertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
    MessageBox.Show("Row inserted !! ");
}
```

Comment: Begin with `adapter.SelectCommand`. But then `adapter.InsertCommand`. I believe the first five should be `adapter.InsertCommand`? And move those 5 statements after `adapter.InsertCommand = new SqlCommand(...)`

Comment: Aside... [AddWithValue is evil](https://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/). [Can we stop using AddWithValue already?](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/)

Comment: You should also specify the exact columns in your insert statement: `insert into client (id, name, lastname, address, email) values (@id, @name, @lastname, @adress, @email)` Otherwise if you ever drop/recreate a column (even keeping the same name) it will change the actual order of columns in your table and break the insert statement.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning I've ceased promoting Joel's "Can we stop.." blog post because it's unnecessarily inclusive; not every database has a problem with it but the post doesn't make this clear. MySQL actively encourage its use. I'm not sure why Joel hasn't improved his advice to be less sweeping

Comment: Why does this need an adapter at all? An adapter is for data-binding, which you are not using here. Just use a plain `SqlCommand`. You also need to dispose the connection, command and adapter with `using`

Comment: Please don't add your solution to the question. If you think its valuable to show then add it as your own answer.

Comment: And I recommend to [stop using AddWithValue](https://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've added parameters to the `SelectCommand`; this does not automatically add them to the `InsertCommand`. The two commands are different things

You don't need an adapter here; just make a new `SqlCommand`, set the SQL, add the parameters to it and execute it